# Extending TRAMP with Subversion Support

Tags: svn, emacs, tramp

After having seen

https://github.com/dougm/vagrant-tramp/blob/master/vagrant-tramp.el

I wonder if anybody has written a similar extension for making svn repos TRAMP-browseable over ssh?

It would be an extra super-bonus if the implementation could make use of keep-alive logic to minimize browsing latency.

Comment: Why the close votes?

Answer (score 1):

In principle, the `dav::` method of Tramp should work on Subversion repositories.  Unfortunately, it is not a native Tramp method: it delegates to `gvfs`, which is a C daemon which pulls in a lot of dependencies.

Comment: I would prefer not having to rely on gvfs. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Fully agreed — something needs to be done about tramp's support for DAV.  Perhaps you can get away with `fusedav`?